# Label sizes changing when run

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

For some reason when I run my view controller in the simulator, the label changes size. For example, a page set up like this:

[image]

Will show up like this when run:

[image]

Its too thick when I run it. The only constraints it has are when I "added missing constraints"

Comment: "The only constraints it has are when I "added missing constraints"" Means you let Xcode assume the constraints. Double check your storyboard and change the constraints to have a set height if that's what you want....

Comment: it is your constraints problems....if you are using autolayout, first have a look at some tutorials how to give constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Give the top , leading , trailing and fixed height to label check below image .

[image]

Output:-

[image]